# Using range-variable to all selected rows

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, range

Below is working VB, but I want to set variable D5:D222, F5:F222 and I5:I222 and to see result in G5:G222.

Below is for single row, but I need it to run for all selected rows. I tried all but I don't know how to set it.

```
Dim score As Integer, result As String

D5 = Range("D5").Value
F5 = Range("F5").Value
I5 = Range("I5").Value

If D5 = 1 And F5 = 1 Then 
  result = "=I5*0.67" 
End If

If D5 = 1 And F5 = 0 Then 
  result = "=I5" 
End If

If D5 = 0 Then 
  result = "0" 
End If

Range("G5").Value = result
```

Comment: Sorry, title need to be "Range varibale to all selected rows"

Comment: Do you need VBA to solve it, formula is not enough?

Comment: Do you actually want a string demonstrating a formula in the first two conditions or are you trying to put a formula into G5? If you want a working formula in the cells then you need `Range("G5").Formula = result`. The zero as a text string will still go into G5 even though it is not a true formula.

Answer (score 0):

If solution with formulas is OK, you can enter in G5:

```
=D5*I5*(1-0.33*F5)
```

and fill it down to row 222

If you want VBA code to calculate the value, you can use:

```
Dim i as Integer
For i = 5 to 222
   Range("G" & i).Value = _
   (Range("I" & i).Value*(1-0.33)*Range("F" & i).Value)*Range("D" & i).Value
Next i
```

If you want VBA code to automatically fill the formula in each cell:

```
Range("G5:G222").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-3]*RC[2]*(1-0.33*RC[-1])"
```

Comment: Nice "ser3964075" this VBA work perfect, this is it :) my wife will be happy. I'am new in VB. Thanks to all